# LEFT JOIN EACH in Bigquery loses rows

Tags: google-bigquery

I have three tables: `a`, `b`, `c`

For simplicity in this example, they all have only one column, an id column. These ids are NEVER `NULL`!

Now I join all three tables:

```
SELECT * FROM 
a
LEFT JOIN EACH b
ON a.id = b.id
LEFT JOIN EACH c
ON b.id = a.id
```

Now the problem:

`b` does not contain all 'ids' from `a`, therefore some `NULL`-values occur, 
when I then join `c`, the rows with these `NULL`-values are removed! From my understanding, `LEFT JOIN` should never remove rows, but only add new ones, right?

Example:

```
a: id = [1,2]
b: id = [1]
c: id = [1]
```

Bigquery would return

```
row1: 1,1,1
```

My expected result:

```
row1: 1,1,1
row4: 2,NULL, NULL
```

Is there a way to get the expected behaviour in BigQuery?

UPDATE:

Thx to @Felipe and @oulenz for the input, i've now tested:

```
select *
from (select 1 as id) a
left outer join (select 2 as id) b
  on b.id = a.id
left outer join (select 2 as id) c
  on c.id = b.id
```

And this yields my expected result `1,null,null` and does not reproduce my problem.

I will have to investigate further where the problem is. Thx for your input so far!

Comment: Is the second join condition a typo, is what you actually queried `c.id = a.id`? (I think `b.id = a.id` isn't even possible in BigQuery (unfortunately!).)

Comment: I am not able to reproduce your problem (I get the expected result). Did you actually do this with tables a,b,c like in your example?

Answer (score 1):

This question is slightly dated.  At the time, this question reflected an issue with how the BigQuery SQL query was translated internally.  This issue was tracked publicly on the [BigQuery public issue tracker issue 35905407](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35905407) (migrated from Google Code to Issue Tracker) and has since been fixed.

Use of `EACH` is no longer recommended and a part of [Legacy SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/legacy-sql#joins) from which Big Query is moving away since adopting Stadard SQL.  If this issue still affects you, I'd recommend removing the `EACH` modifier as mentioned in previous answers/comments or consider [rewriting the query to conform to Standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/migrating-from-legacy-sql).

Answer (score 0):

I tested what you ask for, and it works as you expected it to work:

```
SELECT a.x, b.x, c.x
FROM (
  SELECT x FROM (SELECT 1 x), (SELECT 2 x)
) a
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT 1 x
) b
ON a.x=b.x
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT 1 x
) c
ON a.x=c.x
```

[image]

Comment: Note that your code differs in that you don't use `left join each`. In fact, I am running into a bug when trying to apply `left outer join each` twice on values defined on the spot (as in `select 1 as id`, as opposed to `select id from some_table`).

If the problem signaled by the OP is real, I feel the keywords `each` may be at the heart of the problem.

Comment: same if I add EACH... this works much better when the person asking includes a working query (and if you are running into a bug, please report in a different question or the bug tracker with a job id!)

Comment: I have. https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/detail?id=351 And I agree that even with `each`, I cannot reproduce the result (see comment above).

Comment: You actually joined on a.x=c.x, but it should be b.x=c.x

Comment: Then please correct your question (see my comment up there).

Comment: yes, i will update it as soon as I have to isolated the problem. sry for my mistake